# Why not put acoustic foam over acoustic panels?

Tags: acoustics, room-treatment

I have been doing research on acoustic treatment for my "home studio".  It seems that the general principle for first reflection point panels is to make panels out of porous insulation and then cover it with a suitable fabric, both for aesthetics and to prevent stray insulation fibers from shedding and spreading.  However, [according to the specs for the preferred fabric](https://www.guilfordofmaine.com/swatches/2100-797), the fabric layer causes the panels to have worse performance in the high frequencies. There is a clear trend downward up to 2k, and they don't even bother testing above that, but I'm afraid that the trend continues.

There's an obvious solution to me- build the panel like you normally would, and then add a layer of thin "acoustic foam" on top to take the extra highs out.  But, no one does this.  Is there an acoustical/practical reason that no one does this?

Note that this is specifically for first reflection points- not necessarily for every panel in a room.

Comment: What exact product are you thinking of adding on top? If it’s flat foam, then I expect that will be about the same as fabric. For high frequencies most foam is more about diffusion than absorption, if I understand correctly. This is ok, because as long as there’s no flutter echo, high frequency reflections die out faster than lower frequencies and can also be pleasant, as long as they are sufficiently diffuse.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Foam has substantial high frequency absorption characteristics (not as good as fiberglass, though) and any uneven surface could work as a diffuser.  I'd be using the common "pyramid" foam for this.

Comment: Going by this, it seems like people might not put foam over panels because they want to keep the high frequencies: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20150023091/downloads/20150023091.pdf